# How to trigger a server-side timed deletion?

Tags: meteor

How can I trigger a server-side timed deletion of a file, stored in a collection, based in a timeframe, set in the collection itself?
I tried using cron from inside a post method, I need to set an auto-running delete method that gets the time the file was stored and the amount of time the user wants it to be on, and then let the server delete it when the time comes.

[edited 1]

```
if (! this.isSimulation) {
        Meteor.setTimeout(function () {console.log(postId)}, 5000);
        Meteor.setTimeout(function () {Posts.remove(postId)}, 5000);
}
```

This code seems to be working now, I still need to fix the UI. When you get redirected to the post it has its proper data from the database, but after the remove function it just changes all it's database-based info to undefined. Any ideas about it? Maybe routing or something.

Comment: Post some of your code or what you've done. It can help in getting answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `setTimeout` on the server (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settimeout) that is set in the moment the document is created. This won't work across server-restarts though. So if the timeframe is pretty long, then you would need to store these timers in a collection and re-enable them upon server restart.